# Showing that a subgroup $Gz_0$ of $S^1$ is dense and that the quotient $S^1/G$ is a topological group.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G = \langle e^{i2\pi r}\rangle$ where r is an irrational number and let $Gz_0 = \{ zz_0 | z \in G \}$ where $z_0 \in S^1$. I want to show that $Gz_0$ is dense in $S^1$ and that the function $f:(S^1/G) \times(S^1/G) \to S^1/G$ such that $f(x,y) = xy^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Good for you! What is preventing you from proving these facts?

Comment: @RobArthan Well I am trying to show that $ S^1 \subseteq \overline{G}$ but I am stuck and don't know what to do. For checking the continuity of the function I don't really know how the open sets in $S^1/G$ look like.

Comment: @NuKexZ Recall that $U \subseteq S^1/G$ is open iff $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $S^1$ where $\pi$ is the quptient map. To prove that $f$ is continuous, use the fact that the map $S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \rightarrow S^1/G$ sending $(x,y) \mapsto \pi(xy^{-1})$ is continous.